# QSqlQuery causing ODBC Function sequence error

Tags: c++, sql-server, qt, odbc

I searched SO and Google but didn't find much help on this question. It seems due to ODBC functions being called out out of order. But since I am using QSql that wraps ODBC, it is hard for me to track down the function. Please help...

- I was able to connect to the sql server database
- I tested a very simply query and still got the error. I don't think it's due to column binding.
- I was able to run the query with sql server, so I think the sql query is ok.

  1. The tools I am using:

VS c++ 2017, CMake,  Qt 5.09.2, sql server 2017

2. Below are the error messages:

   QODBCResult::exec: Unable to execute statement: "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Function sequence error"
   QSqlError("0", "QODBC3: Unable to execute statement", "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Function sequence error")
3. Test coding:

This coding generate the error message above.

```
int main()
{
    QSqlDatabase GUIInpDB = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC", "MainSQLDB");
    GUIInpDB.setConnectOptions();
    QString inpSqlServer = "DESKTOP-085AEA8\\SQLEXPRESS";
    QString dbName = "test";
    QString connString = QString("Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=%1;DATABASE=%2;Trusted_Connection=Yes;")
        .arg(inpSqlServer).arg(dbName); //the argument replace the %1 and %2
    GUIInpDB.setDatabaseName(connString);
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database("MainSQLDB");

    if (!db.open())
    {
        qDebug() << "Connection for db not working";
        return 1;
    }
    QSqlQuery query("SELECT * FROM TBL.tbl_test", db);  
    if (!query.exec())
        qDebug() << query.lastError();

    int num_of_rows = query.size();

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` before creating the QSqlQuery 
 [QTBUG-54880](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-54880)

Comment: @MohammadKanan I added "QCoreApplication::processEvents();" before QSqlQuery. I also tried using query.exec(...) as suggested by the bug report, but the still got the same error. Please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this discussion on QtCenter that might help you, even if I am doubtful about why it fixed the issue
You migth try to use the QSqlQuery constructor that does not exec as mentionned

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/18832-ODBC-function-sequence-error

Comment: @sanwood thank you and this worked! I thought I already avoided doing the query twice but I obviously didn't!

Comment: Just to sum up and extract the solution from QtCentre link: The problem is that the query was executed twice: once in the `QSqlQuery` ctor and then, second time, in the `exec()` method. The solution is either to call the constructor with no query string (`QSqlQuery query(db);`) and then put the query string as `exec()`'s argument OR remove the `query.exec()` call, leaving the query string in the constructor.