# Microsoft Access ODBC Driver Manager Function sequence error

Tags: c++, sql, qt, ms-access

I am trying to use Qt to query a table in an MS Access database with a QSqlQuery.  I am able to query all tables, except for one.  The one table returns the error:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Function sequence error
```

Here is the code I use to query the table.

```
QSqlQueryModel *tempModel = new QSqlQueryModel();
QSqlQuery *qry = new QSqlQuery();
qry->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name;");
qry->exec();

tempModel->setQuery(*qry);

while(tempModel->canFetchMore())
{
    tempModel->fetchMore();
}
```

I've tried the answer from this SO question, but no change.
[QSqlQuery causing ODBC Function sequence error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49472159/qsqlquery-causing-odbc-function-sequence-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seemed to be with the Date/Time datatype of one of the columns.

One of my columns had a data type of "Date/Time" with a property of "IME Sentence Mode" set to "Phrase Predict".

Changing this from "Phrase Predict" to "None" allowed me to query the MS Access table from my Qt application.

Answer (score 1):

I too encountered issue with DAO connector to MySql backend.  My passthrough queries were working, but attempt to read from the table using DAO were receiving ODBC function sequence error.  The recordset connector was fine - no problem with move.first, move.last, record count, numerating the field names.  Program failed when attempting to read record data -- but again, no problem was happening with my passthrough queries.

Issue was easy to resolve.  I forgot to refresh my ODBC link after making a table schema changes.  Refreshed the link.. and now everything working normal again.

To simplify my life, I added a program link for end-users to automatically refresh the ODBC links.